# Can I safely hang a 17KG TV on a drywall in the UK?

Tags: electrical, drywall, walls, television

I was wondering if it's possible to hang a 50 inch TV on the wall behind my PC setup? It weighs a total of 17KG.

Here's a link to the TV I'm talking about: [Panasonic TX-50CS520B](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Panasonic-TX-50CS520B-Smart-Freetime-Model/dp/B00U2FEAY0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1455300732&sr=8-1&keywords=50%20inch%20panasonic)

Comment: Something as heavy and expensive as a TV should always hang from studs.  Can you not find them?  Are the studs just in the wrong place?  We have questions and answers that cover both of those issues.

Comment: If your mount is truly flush (such as a two piece bracket) that doesn't extend from the wall at all, AND your drywall is thick (1/2" minimum, preferably 5/8") you could probably (note my weasel words) get away with 4 twist/lock (the big nylon screw type) anchors or toggle/molly anchors.  If the mount holds the TV away from the wall any more than say 4 inches, rethink your approach and find some studs.  Here is some more info: http://www.factsfacts.com/MyHomeRepair/drywallfastenerstrengths.htm

Comment: I'm fairly sure this question has been asked, and answered here before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google tells me [that model](https://www.panasonic.com/uk/consumer/viera-televisions/led/tx-50cs520b.specs.html) is compatible with [VESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface) mounting.

For heavy screens, be sure to buy a mount that is rated sufficiently, and is attached to the structure of your wall. (So for drywall covered stud-framed walls, you'd want to be sure to attach to the structural wooden studs inside the wall, not just the gypsum wallboard.)

You can use a [stud finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_finder) to help locate the studs within the wall.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just one more question, how do I find out where those wooden studs are?

Comment: @CurtisLee I added that info to the answer.